# git push from [remote1] [name1] to [remote2] [name2]?

Tags: git, azure, kudu

I just set up an Azure website and am trying to push with git from an existing repository.  So I ran

```
git push azure master
```

and things sort of worked.  A lot of files got pushed, but I think they came from `origin master`, whereas I would like to push changes from the branch I'm working on `origin web-zach`.  Since I'm not sure how Azure works, I would like to push to the `azure master` branch and not the `azure web-zach` branch.

I'm wondering if there's a simple command I'm missing here?  Something maybe like (this is certainly wrong)

```
git push azure master --otherBranch origin web-zach
```

I'm also not sure if I'm experiencing expected behavior here or if Azure (and Node/Kudu) are messing something up.  `git push azure master` also seems to run some deployment scripts, so it does seem a little weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is

```
git push azure web-zach:refs/heads/master
```

For a little more explanation, a search for "refspec" (from magikid's git man page) uncovered some good articles: http://blog.endpoint.com/2008/07/git-push-know-your-refspecs.html
The default behavior of 
    git push remote_repo some_branch

automatically pushes the local branch named `some_branch` to the remote branch of the same name.  To specify the name of the remote repository I used

```
git push remote_repo local_branch:refs/heads/remote_branch
```

I also got my default "git push azure" command to run the above by changing my .git/config file.  Under `[remote "azure"]` I added:

```
push = refs/heads/web-zach:refs/remotes/azure/master
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the git push command is well documented https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html

You are pushing your master branch to azure.  If you want to push a different branch `git push azure <branchname>`

Comment: I can push the local branch web-zach to azure web-zach - I'm looking to push local web-zach to azure master.